# Differentiation between two using pack() in python

Tags: python, tkinter, pack

I have two code following
the first one:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.pack()
        for keyF in ('123','456','789','-0.'):
            keyFr = Frame(self).pack(side="top")
            for char in keyF:
                but = Button(keyFr, text=char).pack(side='left')    
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]

the second code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.pack()
        for keyF in ('123','456','789','-0.'):
            keyFr = Frame(self)
            keyFr.pack(side="top")
            for char in keyF:
                but = Button(keyFr, text=char)
                but.pack(side='left')
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]

I do not know what is different between using pack in those codes. Could you help me explain the one?

Comment: `keyFr = Frame(self).pack(side="top")` assigns the return value of `pack()` (which is None), NOT the Frame itself.  The wrong value of `keyFr` causes the buttons to be created as children of the root window, rather than the Frame.

Comment: It is very useful for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code does not do what you think:

```
keyFr = Frame(self).pack(side="top")
```

What it does is set `keyFr` to `None`. Why? In python, `x().y()` returns the value of `y()`. Therefore, `Frame(self).pack(side="top")` returns the value of `pack(side="top")`. `pack(...)` always returns `None` so `keyFr` is `None`.

Because `keyFr` is none, all of the buttons in the first block of code are getting added to the root window rather than the frame.